# JRXML - Display a checkbox in a table

Tags: checkbox, jasper-reports, xmltable

I can't manage to display a checkbox in a table in *jrxml*.

Here is a sample of my code:

```xml
<detail>
    <band height="45" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement style="MyCustomStyle" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="650" y="0" width="80" height="35"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Boolean"><![CDATA[$F{myBooleanVariable}]]>
            </textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

The column just displays **true** or **false**. I supposed that specifying `class="java.lang.Boolean"` in the ***textFieldExpression*** element would convert the value to a checkbox but apparently, I need more than that.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al right so apparently it's not possible to add a checkbox in a table with that language !

So now I just display YES/NO:

```
<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{myBooleanVariable}?"YES":"NO"]]></textFieldExpression>
```

That's the best I could find !

Answer (score 7):

Simple, do this, on the tag ->imageExpression<-

```
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement x="196" y="109" width="46" height="39"/>
            <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                <datasetRun subDataset="dataset3">
                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{fisicos})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                </datasetRun>
                <jr:listContents height="39" width="46">
                    <image>
                        <reportElement x="12" y="0" width="17" height="21"/>
                        <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{_THIS} == true ? $P{checkboxFisicoOK} : $P{checkboxFisicoNOK}]]></imageExpression>
                    </image>
                </jr:listContents>
            </jr:list>
        </componentElement>
```

[image]

- checkboxFisicoOK: is a parameter of the image path.

  ```
  <parameter name="checkboxFisicoOK" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
      <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new java.lang.String("/Users/ccamol/onprocess/checkboxOK.jpg")]]></defaultValueExpression>
  </parameter>
  ```

Comment: Great. That should be the accepted one.

Just one detail: You have to deifne 2 parameters: checkboxFisicoOK and checkboxFisicoNOK

Comment: upvoted for adding the image ... none in this thread posted output of their code except your answer.   picture speaks..

Answer (score 6):

I just added some unicode to the solution you already made:

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{myBooleanVairiable}? "\u2713":"\u2717"]]></textFieldExpression>
```

`u2713` translates to a tick mark and `u2717` to a cross

Remember to make sure you're encoding statement at the top of your xml page is set to UTF8:

Comment: Unfortunally this doesn't seem to work when you export the report to pdf format. I tried several font types and no one seems to work.

Comment: Explicitly use a font containing the glyph in question. Fonts in PDF exports are a special beast in Jasper.

Answer (score 4):

Checkbox in the the jasper HTML report can be as follows

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{myBooleanVairiable}? "\u2713":"\u2717"]]></textFieldExpression>
```

Note: Have to use the font which supports the unicode

In PDF above code cannot be used. Either we have to use font extension or by drawing lines as follows

```
<frame>
<reportElement x="161" y="73" width="12" height="12"/>
<box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
</box>
<line>
    <reportElement x="2" y="7" width="2" height="2">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Boolean Exprssion]></printWhenExpression>
    </reportElement>
</line>
<line direction="BottomUp">
    <reportElement x="4" y="3" width="6" height="6">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Boolean Exprssion]]]></printWhenExpression>
    </reportElement>
</line>
```

Answer (score 1):

For PDF this worked for me, explicitly setting the font to one that supports unicode:

```
<textField>
    <textElement>
        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="16"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{myBooleanVariable}?"\u2611" : "\u2610"]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Answer (score 0):

Supplement to Olezt's answer, "DejaVu Sans" font, or "Segoe UI Symbol" works for ticked checkbox, including export to pdf through
Jasper Studio

To make it works for JaserReport Server, need to Add the font to both Jasper Studio and Jasper Server.

1. Get the ttf file of the font, either from Windows\font or from Internet.
2. In Jasper Studio, Window->Preference->Jaspersoft Studio->Fonts
3. Click Add
4. Input the Family Name of the font (e.g. Segoe UI Symbol 1)
5. In TrueType (.ttf), Browse the ttf get in step (1) above
6. Tick "Embed this font in PDF document"
7. Select "Identity-H (Unicode with horizontal writing)" in PDF Encoding.
8. Click "Next" (Don't click Finish)
9. Add "html", "rtf", "xhtml" Font Mapping.  The Font Name should be that in step (4) above.
10. Click Finish
11. The new added font is shown in the "Preferences" window. Select it and click "Export" to get the jar.  This is to put to Jasper Server
12. Put the jar to "C:\Jaspersoft\jasperreports-server-cp-6.3.0\apache-tomcat\webapps\jasperserver\WEB-INF\lib" of your jasper server and restart server.
13. To add checkbox, find the "html entity" first. e.g. ☑ for Ballotbox with check, and ☐ for unchecked. https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2611
14. Back to the Jaspersoft Studio, in the "Text Field" showing the checkbox, select the newly added font, and select "html" for Markup.
15. Generate, test, deploy, and enjoy.

Ref: https://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/13056

Ref: https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/custom-font-font-extension#Publish_the_Font_to_the_Server